# How to accept user input in Visual Studio Code integrated Terminal?

Tags: c, powershell, visual-studio-code, terminal

I've searched for this answer but it was futile, a lot of threads are open with no answer whatsoever or the answer is just not the one that was asked.

How do I use the integrated terminal that comes on the bottom of VS:Code?

[image: Terminal VS Code overview]

That allows the user to input and also see the text that is printed on the terminal when one normally executes a program.

I'm learning `C` and I can't make it work there.

As you can see, if I run my code through the debugger, it doesn't work, AKA does not allow user input.

[image: User input is not accepted]

Keep in mind that this is what happens if I use `launch.json` option called
`"externalConsole": ,` and set it to true.
[image: External console]

But also this has it's drawbacks (for example as soon as the code finishes running the console exits and ceases existence therefore one can't read the output of the program)

How can this be solved? I've seen it working fine but on Linux environment computers.
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `launch.json` file has a `"console"` setting, which you must set to `"integratedTerminal"` (the default is `"internalConsole"`, which only displays *output* from your program).

- The `launch.json` file is the configuration for your project's debugging sessions. You can open it via the command palette with `Debug: Open launch.json` or by clicking the cogwheel icon in the toolbar at the top of the `Run` view:
  [image]

Starting a debugging session automatically switches to the `DEBUG CONSOLE` tab in the panel (lower window pane).
Switch to `TERMINAL` to interact with your console application.

See [the docs](https://aka.ms/VSCode-CS-LaunchJson-Console) for more information.